# Estimate E[x|A,B]: alternatives to bucketing for non-parametric estimation

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have a set of products. I would like to estimate Expected Value of items sold of the products wrt product price and age of the purchaser.

One alternative is to assume a distribution and fit it.

One other way, non-parametric, is to estimate the quantity by bucketing the data and estimating the desired quantity by averaging the sample points in each bucket.
What are the alternatives to bucketing for non-parametric estimation?

New to the subject, could you pin point me to relevant literature so I could also build up the proper technical jargon?

Comment: Your definition of nonparametric is restrictive. Use [GAMs](http://www3.nd.edu/~mclark19/learn/GAMS.pdf) to flexibly model the conditional expectation function.

Comment: Thanks but gams' still require an assumption on functional forms.

Comment: As opposed to what technique? Bucketing implies a piecewise constant "functional form".

Comment: Yes, I agree, within the bucket. My focus is trying to understand whether it would make sense to estimate the expected value of the number of items sold making use of other methodologies that do not require bucketing ([kernel estimators](http://mason.gmu.edu/~jgentle/csi9723/11s/l13_11s.pdf), perhaps). Are you suggesting fitting a gam in the bucket? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very loosely, kernel and spline-based methods are complementary approaches to estimating flexible functional forms. Kernel estimators are a generalization of the bucketing approach, but are typically harder to compute, and theoretical guarantees on performance are harder to come by.